# When RaisePropertyChanged will executed?

Tags: c#, wpf

I could not target a break point in SET property of View Model, so the default value not changed. (Get - is all right and it initialize my Text Box with valid default value. )

I have a model.cs 
where a public string field defined

```
model.cs
{
..
public textDefValue = "aaa";
}
```

and here is a ViewModel

```
{
.. 
 Model model = new Model();
....
 public string TextField
        {
            get { return model.textDefValue; }
            set
            {
               //break point here
                model.textDefValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(TextField);
            }
        }
 ....
   protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myBox" Text="{Binding ViewModel.TextField, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

I suppose that when I will type something in this Text Box the SET will work and I will target a break point but, I could not hit this break in SET. Where is a bug?

Comment: where is the ViewModel defined, mostly it will go over a resource that would then be referred to as `Text="{Binding TextField, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource KeyOfViewModelInResources}}"`

Comment: It was difficult to translate all of that, but the issue probably has something to do with your `Binding`. Check the **Output Window** for clues. Also, you don't need to create a property in your View Model just to expose your Model's property. You could instead just bind to the Model's property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no bug, just a misunderstanding.

By default, the binding for a control's `.Text` property is only updated when you leave the box (i.e. move focus to a different control). You'd need to click or Tab away for the value to update and the breakpoint to be hit.

You can change this behaviour by updating your binding as follows:

```
Text="{Binding ViewModel.TextField, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

This will cause the binding to update every time the text value changes - that is, per-keypress in your text box.

Comment: Sorry for one more question here - It seems that I have crashed something((. No the Get did not work too - I have add the string you suggested, but .. I have initialized model instance in constructor of ViewModel, but in XAML I have different datacontext then  ViewModel - it is another class

Comment: @curiousity that is a totally unrelated problem and you would need to ask a new question with the relevant code to re-create the issue.